# Multi_Curl using authentication

Tags: php, authentication, curl

I am trying to login to a site and then call numerous URLs to get the source and scrape for images. It works fine using regular curl but when I try to use multi_curl I am getting back the exact same response. So that I only have to login once I am resuing the curl resource (this works fine with regular curl) and I think this may be the reason why it is returning the same response.

Does anyone know how to use multi_curl but authenticate first?

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php
    // LICENSE: PUBLIC DOMAIN
    // The author disclaims copyright to this source code.
    // AUTHOR: Shailesh N. Humbad
    // SOURCE: http://www.somacon.com/p539.php
    // DATE: 6/4/2008

    // index.php
    // Run the parallel get and print the total time
    $s = microtime(true);
    // Define the URLs
    $urls = array(
      "http://localhost/r.php?echo=request1",
      "http://localhost/r.php?echo=request2",
      "http://localhost/r.php?echo=request3"
    );
    $pg = new ParallelGet($urls);
    print "<br />total time: ".round(microtime(true) - $s, 4)." seconds";

    // Class to run parallel GET requests and return the transfer
    class ParallelGet
    {
      function __construct($urls)
      {
        // Create get requests for each URL
        $mh = curl_multi_init();
        $count = 0;
        $ch = curl_init();

        foreach($urls as $i => $url)
        {
            $count++;

            if($count == 1)
            {
                // SET URL FOR THE POST FORM LOGIN
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.example.com/login.php');

                // ENABLE HTTP POST
                curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

                // SET POST PARAMETERS : FORM VALUES FOR EACH FIELD
                curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user=myuser&password=mypassword');

                // IMITATE CLASSIC BROWSER'S BEHAVIOUR : HANDLE COOKIES
                curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/cookie.txt');

                # Setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER variable to 1 will force cURL
                # not to print out the results of its query.
                # Instead, it will return the results as a string return value
                # from curl_exec() instead of the usual true/false.
                curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

                // EXECUTE 1st REQUEST (FORM LOGIN)
                curl_exec ($ch);

            }

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/cookie.txt');
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $ch_array[$i] = $ch;
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch_array[$i]);
        }

        // Start performing the request
        do {
            $execReturnValue = curl_multi_exec($mh, $runningHandles);
        } while ($execReturnValue == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
        // Loop and continue processing the request
        while ($runningHandles && $execReturnValue == CURLM_OK) {
          // Wait forever for network
          $numberReady = curl_multi_select($mh);
          if ($numberReady != -1) {
            // Pull in any new data, or at least handle timeouts
            do {
              $execReturnValue = curl_multi_exec($mh, $runningHandles);
            } while ($execReturnValue == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
          }
        }

        // Check for any errors
        if ($execReturnValue != CURLM_OK) {
          trigger_error("Curl multi read error $execReturnValue\n", E_USER_WARNING);
        }

        // Extract the content
        foreach($urls as $i => $url)
        {
          // Check for errors
          $curlError = curl_error($ch_array[$i]);
          if($curlError == "") {
            $res[$i] = curl_multi_getcontent($ch_array[$i]);
          } else {
            print "Curl error on handle $i: $curlError\n";
          }
          // Remove and close the handle
          curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch_array[$i]);
          curl_close($ch_array[$i]);
        }
        // Clean up the curl_multi handle
        curl_multi_close($mh);

        // Print the response data
        print_r($res);
      }

    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to enable/use cookies with curl as well. look for it on the documentation, don't forget to create the cookies (empty files) with read and write permission for curl.

```
    $cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie );
```

Comment: it works fine using regular curl, but when I use multi_curl I have some trouble. I added my code so you can see what I am doing.

Comment: I looked into the docs like you said and used the CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR options to reuse the cookie and it is now working. Thanks!